# Wanted to take thread dump in windows 10?

Tags: java, java-8

I want to take thread dump for the windows 10 machine. I am using `java version "1.8.0_131"` . To take the thread dump i need to use jmap command followed by  of the process. But in my JDK i didnt find jmap utility. Even when i tried in my machine i am getting error like this :

```
C:\Users\Name\Desktop\JavaHeap>jmap
'jmap' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

My JDk version

```
C:\Users\Name\Desktop\JavaHeap>java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And also it seems it is running on Client VM . Is there any way to change it to Server Vm?

--INFO--
I kept my JRE in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131` . I created system environment variable JAVA_HOME and kept this path to it. And also in PATH variable too i added the path.

Thanks

Comment: Make sure jmap is in your PATH environment variable

Comment: Thanks @SantiagoBenoit updated my comments in INFO section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a **PATH** problem.

Make sure that the file **jmap.exe** is located in a path specified in the system variable **PATH** of Windows.

As you have added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_131` to the variable, are you sure that **jmap.exe** is located there? Usually it is in the **JDK\bin** and not in **JRE\bin**.

The JRE (*Java Runtime Environment*) only contains stuff that is needed to run Java programs whereas the JDK also includes tools useful for developement (*Java Developer Kit*).

Windows searches for commands in all paths specified in systems **PATH** variable. If there is no **jmap.exe** inside those locations it will not find it.

As you can see, my JDK includes *jmap.exe*: [image]

If yours does not include one I would check where you got it and try another source like **Oracle** for example.